# Unexpected behaviour using a shell script to run a command in python shell

Tags: python, django, bash, docker

I'm attempting to write a script for the initial setup of superuser in django. I have a docker container running django.

```sh
docker exec -it "mydockername" bash -c echo "from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.create_superuser('root3', 'admin3@myproject.com', 'root3')" | python manage.py shell
```

This script is throwing an error

```
      File "manage.py", line 16
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But if I execute the command

```sh
echo "from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.create_superuser('root3', 'admin3@myproject.com', 'root3')" | python manage.py shell
```

inside of the docker container I don't have any problems and the superuser is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the last half of your command so that `bash -c` gets a single argument.  This makes the entire command kind of complicated (since it already uses both single and double quotes), but it'd look like

```sh
docker exec -it "mydockername" \
  bash -c "echo \"from django.contrib.auth import ...\" | python manage.py shell"
```

Without this, your local shell gets first stab at picking the command apart and it sees

```sh
docker exec ... | python manage.py shell
```

And furthermore, since `bash -c` accepts only a single argument, the command getting run inside the container is

```sh
bash -c echo  # with another argument that gets ignored
```

You could probably run this command directly on your host (without `docker exec`). You'd need to write an alternate `settings.py` file that points at the Docker-hosted database (the database host name would be `localhost` and its port whatever is published via `ports:`) and then those settings could reach the database inside the container.

Probably the best path here is to avoid writing a Python script run via a quoted shell command launched through `docker exec`.  Write a small extension script, as discussed in the Django documentation [Writing custom `django-admin` commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) page:

```python
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
class CreateSuperuser(BaseCommand):
  def handle(self, *args, **options):
    User = get_user_model()
    User.objects.create_superuser('root3', 'admin3@myproject.com', 'root3')
```

Place this in `management/commands/superuser.py`, and you can run `python manage.py superuser` (potentially via `docker exec`).  The Django documentation discusses ways to add arguments and write output.

Comment: Thank you to much, now I understand my mistake and you are right I should create a custom command in django .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
docker exec -it "mydockername" bash -c "echo \"from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.create_superuser('root3', 'admin3@myproject.com', 'root3')\" | python manage.py shell"
```